# Can I use ASP.NET Membership with SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, asp.net-membership

I`m using SQL Server Compact Edition and ASP.NET DynamicData for the Admin area of a website.

I want to use ASP.NET membership using SQL Server CE. I'm aware of the fact that SQL Server CE does not supports sprocs, which are essential part of ASP.NET membership.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you run SQL Server Express instead? It will work with that for sure.

Comment: You should change the accepted answer now that asp.net universal providers are available.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant use SQLCE compact edition for ASP.NET Membership like @JustinStolle said You can use Sql Express for this or if you already have sql server exists use it as your backend.

Regards.