# How to use SQL Server Compact 4.0 DB file by default for ASP.NET Website?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, webforms, sql-server-ce

Is there a way to change the database option that Visual Studio uses by default when creating a new website? Basically I want to use a SQL Server Compact file as default instead of a SQL Server Express DB when setting up my membership database. Does anyone know how to do this or at least set up my website to use the Compact File for membership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx#7550165) comment by ScottGu, out of the box there isn't a membership provider that supports SQL CE.

> Thursday, July 01, 2010 12:44 AM by
>   ScottGu @Lee,
>
> -- I'm assuming since stored procedured aren't supported, you won't
>   be able to do ASP.NET Membership or
>   Profiles with it. Correct?
>
> We are looking to potentially ship a
>   set of providers that work with it
>   (and do not use stored procedures). 
>   The first beta won't have this - but
>   it is something we'll hopefully enable
>   in the future.
>
> Hope this helps,
>
> Scott

[There was also a similar question asked before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575165/can-i-use-asp-net-membership-with-sql-server-compact-edition)  Looks like you'll need to use this: [SQL Compact ASP.NET Membership, Role and Profile provider](http://sqlcemembership.codeplex.com/).

Comment: You can get the provider via NuGet, it makes (most of) your web.config changes for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking here: [SQL Compact 4 Blog](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/sql-server-compact-40-released.html)

Looks like you need to download a few items, and be on VS2010 SP1 to get the integration you're looking for.

Also how to do it exactly [here](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/08/sql-server-compact-40-aspnet-membership.html)