# Membership provider name and type for Microsoft WebMatrix's sample Template

Tags: asp.net, web-config, webmatrix

What is the membership provider name and type is used in the Microsoft Webmatrix's template site? In the web.config it is not given. When I run it locally, the template works but when I publish, it gives the following error:

Parser Error Message: The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

Source Error:

```
Line 239:      <providers>
Line 240:        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, ....
```

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line: 240

Any help will be appreciated.

The Database used in the application is SQLCE4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Pages uses the `SimpleMembershipProvider` which is located in `WebMatrix.WebData`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a default Membership provider that supports SQL Server Compact Edition 4.  There *is* a Membership provider implementation that does out on CodePlex: http://sqlcemembership.codeplex.com/

So, if you're using that already, then ensure that you have a connection string defined in your config file, like so:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" 
       connectionString="data source=|DataDirectory|\YourDatabaseName.sdf"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And your **provider** specified in your config should define the `connectionStringName` attribute and reference the connection string's name defined in the `<connectionStrings>` block, like this:

```
<providers>
  <clear/>
  <add name="SqlCeMembershipProvider" 
       type="ErikEJ.SqlCeMembershipProvider" 
       connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
       .... />
</providers>
```

A config sample is provided with that SQL CE 4 Membership provider on the main [project page](http://sqlcemembership.codeplex.com/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575165/can-i-use-asp-net-membership-with-sql-server-compact-edition/5575283#5575283

Comment: I could not find the provider name in the application. The application is using Microsoft.web.helper.dll files in the Bin directory and the coding is based on Razor.

Comment: Do you have a web.config file for you application? That's where these config lines should be located.  Your local configuration settings (in web.config) will override the information in machine.config.