# How can I store session in SQL server in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to store session in SQL Server in ASP.NEt MVC3 because I want to share session and some data between two application. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Despite Darin's answer and my upvote for it - my feeling is that you should know that [Stackoverflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/145600).
You have not described what you have tried; or shown any research you've conducted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use ASP.NET Membership with SQL Server Compact Edition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575165/can-i-use-asp-net-membership-with-sql-server-compact-edition).  I'm saying this because on Darin's answer you have said that that question gave you the answer and on it's own, as I've said, this question is poor

Answer (score 9):

By setting the [`<sessionState>`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604) in your web.config:

```
<sessionState 
    mode="SQLServer"
    sqlConnectionString="data source=SQLServerName;user id=<username>;password=<strongpassword>"
/>
```

This assumes that you have created the `ASPState` database first on the target database server using the [`aspnet_regsql.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx) utility:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S SQLServerName -E -ssadd -sstype p
```

Make sure that you run this utility from the correct .NET framework directory. For example if you are using .NET 4.0 this would be `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`.

Once the database is created on the SQL server you could assign an user account to access it and it is this user account that you should specify in the connection string.

Comment: If I using "Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" and Entity Framework, then how will I do that..??

Comment: ASP.NET Session SQL storage has nothing to do with Entity Framework. It uses stored procedures to update the database. I am not sure whether you could use SQL Server Compact for ASP.NET Session storage.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov +1 this is a very generous answer - I can't help thinking this question deserves a [Stackoverflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/145600)

Comment: In SQL Server Compact I can only access database when I connect it through VS2010, then only I can see database. So How to use aspnet_regsql.exe for that. Sorry If I sound stupid because I new to MVC3 and Entity Framework.

Comment: That's what I said in my previous comment. I am not sure whether `aspnet_regsql.exe` supports SQL Server Compact for session state persistence.

Comment: Found answer in following link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575165/can-i-use-asp-net-membership-with-sql-server-compact-edition)..@Darin Thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

if you are using `asp.net mvc5` and storing model object into session then you need to put that model as `Serializable` as shown in `

```
[Serializable]
public class MyModel
{
```

its important when in ajax call. and to send to interpret to sql server